# Cambiar color a la etiqueta li que se encuentra dentro del ol en una galería de Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Quiero saber como cambiar el color de los puntos que aparecen en la galería o carousel de Bootstrap (versión 3.1.0). He intentado poniendo un `span`, pero tampoco funciona. Adjunto imagen de los puntos a modificar.

[image: Puntos a modificar]

Y con la misma galería o carousel tengo el problema de que no puedo reducir el espacio que ocupa. Quisiera que ocupe menos espacio así no se ve de esta manera (Expandido y con mala calidad). Adjunto imagen

[image: El carousel sin modificar tamaño]

El código de los puntos que tengo es este:

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <span><li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="puntos-clientes active"></li></span>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1" class="puntos-clientes" ></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="7"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="8"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="9"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="10"></li>
            </ol>

<!--Carousel-->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes2.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="https://www.discorweb.com"><img src="images/clientes1.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes4.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes7.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes5.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes6.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes3.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes8.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes9.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/clientes10.jpg" /></a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Y lo que he intentado en CSS (para los puntos) es esto:

```
.puntos-clientes{
    color: #7d060a;
    background-color: #7d060a;

}

ol > li > span{
    color: #7d060a;
    background-color: #7d060a;
}
```

Comment: intenta ponerles !important a ver si te toma el cambio

Comment: Buenas, por favor crea un [mre] suficiente para simular el problema. Hasta ahora, solo veo esto, que no se parece nada. https://jsfiddle.net/udqyh8e4/

Comment: @HeynerMartinez en dónde pongo !important?

Comment: Listo @Excorpion. Tendría que estar. Recuerda que es con Bootstrap

Comment: .puntos-clientes{
    color: #7d060a !important;
    background-color: #7d060a !important;
}

Comment: Funcionó @HeynerMartinez!! Saludos!!

Comment: @HeynerMartinez ¿Cómo puedo hacer para hacer más chico el carousel?

Comment: .carousel .item {
  height: 300px;
}

.item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
} prueba con esto

Comment: @HeynerMartinez !important es la peor recomendación que puedes darle a alguien en CSS, si el OP usa clases propias y no las está tomando como prioridad, es porque está llamando primero su CSS y luego Bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.carousel-indicators li{
    background-color: #7d060a !important;
}
```

EDITO:
Es un código CSS, así que puedes ponerlo en tu archivo .css que tengas vinculado al html5. Significa que le estás cambiando los atributos de la clase de boostrap que determina esos estilos.

Si quieres saber como cambiar esos estilos, puedes recurrir  a tu navegador (Chrome por ejemplo) con el botón derecho clicas encima de lo que quieres cambiar, y pulsas la opción de inspeccionar, te abrirá las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador, te señalará la parte de tu código que necesitas cambiar y los atributos CSS correspondientes.

Así sabrás como se llaman y que valores tienen para cambiar.

Comment: ¿Y donde pongo esas líneas? ¿Qué significan? ¿Qué enseñanza obtengo de esta respuesta?

Comment: Es un código CSS, así que puedes ponerlo en tu archivo .css que tengas vinculado al html5. Significa que le estás cambiando los atributos de la clase de boostrap que determina esos estilos. Si quieres saber como cambiar esos estilos, puedes recurrir  a tu navegador (Chrome por ejemplo) con el botón derecho clicas encima de lo que quieres cambiar, y pulsas la opción de inspeccionar, te abrirá las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador, te señalará la parte de tu código que necesitas cambiar un los atributos CSS correspondientes.  Así sabrás como se llaman y que valores tienen para cambiar.

Comment: Así es una respuesta provechosa.